# I am using pyinstller to make package of my project, but it gives error when i run that exc file in another pc

Tags: python, unix, package, pyinstaller

it gives error  when i run that exc file in another PC. but in my pc that exc file run smoothly , but in another pc it error like this ,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "Create_table/create_table_PT.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "db_connection.py", line 12, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
[41403] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: if any have any idea about this then please share any idea how to solve this .

Comment: Do you have some relative pathes in your code? Also it would be nice to see the code. Especially I want to see how you connect to the database.

Comment: @Alex i am using this code to connect database.?
# file: db_connection.py
import os
import sqlite3

db_file=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'database.db')
conn=sqlite3.connect(db_file)

Comment: You need to present a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.  Without that, we can only guess at what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

just try command:-  pyinstaller --onefile "your python file name"

Comment: it's not working i try this one also.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).